# Oracle select on single table

Tags: oracle, select

I Have the following table.

```
id  NAME    folder_NAME
1   tom     popular
2   tom     folder2
3   peter   popular
4   peter   folder1
5   john    folder1
6   john    folder2
7   john    folder3
8   Mark    folder1
9   Mark    folder2
10  Alex    folder1
```

How do I select the names that do not have a folder name 'popular' ?

Comment: select distinct name from folders where f.folder_name != 'popular' , but it still returns all names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct NAME 
  from table
 where name not in (select name from table where folder_name = 'popular')
```

but this is not the best query, which could be written.
I would prefer here NOT EXISTS clause.

Comment: Overly complex solution for something so simple.

Comment: maybe, but it works just as it should... the answer with : select * from your_table where folder_name != 'popular' is not good. One person can have more than one folder, and we have to select only persons, who do not have 'popular' in their folder set.

Comment: Right, it's all about the requirements and getting them clear.

Comment: Yes Colin apologies, I should have been more clear in my question.